# Fluid: How to convert the simulation to a series of meshes?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Once you've baked your fluid simulation, you can apply the *Fluid* in the *Modifier* panel in order to get one mesh that you can edit etc...

But how can you get the whole series of meshes, i.e. one mesh per frame?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here.  Maybe it's just me, but can you elaborate more?

Comment: well, I wanted to answer your question but Lemon gave me the answer, I hope it's clear

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139591/export-fluid-simulation-for-usage-in-three-js  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181773/meshing-a-smoke-simulation

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/is-it-possible-to-export-object-from-blender-with-modifiers-and-use-them-in-exte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get obj (wavefront) meshes in the cache directory as [indicated here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/domain/cache.html#cache).

> Mesh File Format (Liquids Only)
>
> ```
> File format for the mesh cache files.
>
> Binary Object 
>     Mesh data files with some compression.
>
> Object
>     Simple, standard data format for mesh data.
> ```

The settings:

[image]

- Check *"Mesh"*
- In the cache part, set the directory you want
- Choose "object" as format for the meshes

Once the simulation played, if you go to the cache directory, you'll see:

[image]

and the meshes in obj format are in the *"mesh"* subdirectory. One per frame.

So that you can import them:

[image]

Comment: Oh fantastic, thanks

Comment: wooooooooooooooow +1